# bbox loading problem

Tags: openlayers, bbox

Could you tell me why bbox loading all data beginning?

'bbox=' + extent.join(','); },  strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox

The map then loads very long. How can I make it calculate correctly?

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE! You need to provide more information for us to be able to really help you. From your use of "ol.loadingstrategy" i guess you are using OpenLayers. Which version do you use? Also, what is the data source?

Answer (score 1):

The BBOX strategy will load all features from within a BBOX, so maybe your extent is too large. Try loading with a smaller extent.